# UIPageControl select dot and go to that page

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a`UIViewController`, which has inside a `UIView` in which I add a `UIPageViewController` with the `UIViewController` as the delegate. The thing is that the `UIPageControl` of the `UIPageViewController` is not working as I had expected regarding the dots selection.

I was expecting that if I selected the dot 4, it would take me to the dot 4, yet, It doesn't work like that. It always goes to the following page if I select the right half of the `UIPageControl` (inside the blue square of the image), and goes to the previous page if I select the left half of the `UIPageControl` (inside the red square of the image). So, If im in page 2 and select around the second dot, it goes to page 1 (instead of staying on page 2)

[image]

Moreover, If I click exactly inside one of the dots (any of the dots), the click is ignored, although im not sure how this works on device (since in the device is more difficult to click exactly inside one dot).

My questions:

1 - Is ignoring exactly inside the dots behavior normal (by exactly inside the dots, I mean not around them)?

2 - Is two halves selection of the UIPageController to move between pages behavior normal?

3 - How can I make it so that if I press the dot X, it takes me to page X (instead of the current two halves behavior)?

Note: I prefer swift

Comment: Yes, #1 and #2 are normal. You could try implementing your own gesture recognizer to get the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Is ignoring exactly inside the dots behavior normal (by exactly inside the dots, I mean not around them)?

I've never encountered this. I would say its not normal. Something may be overriding it.

> 2 - Is two halves selection of the UIPageController to move between pages behavior normal?

Yes this is the default behavior for UIPageController.

> 3 - How can I make it so that if I press the dot X, it takes me to page X (instead of the current two halves behavior)?

I would recommend not doing this. The reason that it isn't this way by default is the touch space is too small (when using a finger not a mouse). So it makes sense to only go forward and back. You'd have to create a custom UIControl to be able to do this if you really need to for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use external library for that, as this problem was more or less solved. It is quite complicated to do by subclassing native page control but you can probably find implementation somewhere.

This library does exactly what you want (jump to page) :

https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl

In the documentation, look for section "Direct Page Selection"

Hope it helps!

Edit: Few more libraries to look into:

https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/TAPageControl
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl (very extensive, probably too much)